# how to write JSON string's quotes into echoed PHP to prepare it for jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, json, string

I looked for some examples but I couldn't find any relevant to my slight problem. I have a string in PHP:

```
echo '<div class="testdiv" data-test="{"name":"John"}">TEST</div>';
```

I'm trying to include JSON string into data attribute of the HTML element (as above) to be able to get it with jQuery `.data()` later on and actually use it as `.data().name`.

So I wrote my jQuery:

```
jQuery( '.some-button' ).click( function() {
    var test = jQuery( '.testdiv' ).data( 'test' );
    console.log( test );
});
```

Console output shows just `{` and when I add `.name` to `.data( 'test' )` it shows *undefined*. I'm not sure how to write the JSON string to be able to use it in the `.data( 'test' ).name` form. Could anyone help me with this? Thank you and best regards!

Comment: `echo '<div class="testdiv" data-test=\'{"name":"John"}\'>TEST</div>';`

Comment: @Metalik Hahaha, quotes escaping. Must have had a brain fade. Make this comment an answer and I accept it :)

Comment: @pradeep nope, that solution throws PHP error as it thinks I'm quitting the string to put some php in there and there no valid PHP in between those single quotes. Those single quotes should be escaped as in above comment. Thank for your time anyway!

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/GlauberRocha/Q6kKU/

Comment: @pradeep But is that HTML written inside of standard HTML file or is it PHP echoed? If it's PHP echoed and you wrap whatever you echo in single quotes (just like in my example above) those quotes around JSON string need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

As **@Metalik** mentioned in the comment, it was enough to change double quotes to single quotes around curly brackets and escape them, like so:

```
echo '<div class="testdiv" data-test=\'{"name":"John"}\'>TEST</div>';
```